Trying to use specific color data from vertices generated through a csv file
I've created a series of vertices that were imported from a csv file (each point was read in with x,y,z,r,g,b data). My goal is to create a plane and color it accurately according to the rgb data of each point.
I've attempted a data transfer by first duplicating the vertices, then turning the copy into a mesh via Convex Hull, and transferring the color from the points by mapping nearest vertex. I'm not sure what else to try.


What's the context? What is this? Why do you need this? There might be important requirements and constraints of the problem in the context.

You probably need a plane that has matching vertices. There are probably other ways, but one I can think of would be to:

Extrude the verts up a bit and convert the mesh to curve.

Give the curve some small bevel with lowest resolution(no need for the resulting cylinders to be high poly) and convert back to mesh



Now you can make a plane and use the little 'cylinders' to cut holes in it with a boolean("Exact" algorithm seems to be useless at this(like most of the time), so use the "Fast" one in the boolean modifier if you get problems). You should end up with a plane with bunch of holes in it:



You can select the boundary loop in edge mode, deselect the outer edges of your plane and then scale every hole to 0 with Individual Origins selected as transform pivot point. You probably want to merge the vertices by distance at that point.



Now you can triangulate resulting geometry and run Beautify Faces function on it and you have a plane with the verts on it:


Now transferring attributes should work better since you have matching vertices.

Thank you for the detailed response. Ultimately, I was unable to transfer the color, but this did answer part of my issue, which was how to map pre-defined vertices to a plane.

It is possible to transfer color from vertices based on their position. If you provide more info and some example data, maybe a .blend file, I am sure somebody could help with that in more detail.
